# Send an image as the body of a request, image recived with a request from outside

Tags: node.js, api, express, raw-data

Yeah i kinda didn't know how to type the title well...
I've a node server which recives an image via post form. I then want to send this image to Microsoft vision and the same Google service in order to gether information from both, do some stuff, and return a result to the user that has accessed my server.
My problem is: how do i send the actual data?

This is the actual code that cares of that:

```
const microsofComputerVision = require("microsoft-computer-vision");

module.exports = function(req, res)
{
var file;
if(req.files)
    {
    file = req.files.file;

    // Everything went fine
    microsofComputerVision.analyzeImage(
        {
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": vision_key,
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data",
        "body": file.data.toString(),
        "visual-features":"Tags, Faces",
        "request-origin":"westcentralus"
        }).then((result) => 
            {
            console.log("A");
            res.write(result);
            res.end();
            }).catch((err)=>
            {
            console.log(err);
            res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.write(JSON.stringify({error: "The request must contain an image"}));
            res.end();
            });
    }
else
    {
    res.writeHead(400, {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify({error: "The request must contain an image"}));
    res.end();
    }

}
```

If instead of calling "analyzeImage" i do the following

```
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpg')
    res.send(file.data);
    res.end();
```

The browser renders the image correctly, which made me think "file.data" contains the actual file (considered it's of type buffer).
But apparently Microsoft does not agree with that, because when i send the request to computer vision i get the following response:
"InvalidImageFormat"

The only examples i found are [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-computer-vision), and the "data" that is used in that example comes from a file system read, not stright from a request. But saving the file to load it and then delete it to me looks like an horrible workaround, so i'd rather like to know in what form and how should i work on the "file" that i have to send it correctly for the APIs call.

---

Edit: if i use file.data (which i thought was the most correct since it would be sending the raw image as the body) i get an error which says that i must use a string or a buffer as content. So apparently that file.data is not a buffer in the way "body" requires O.o i'm not understanding honestly.

---

Solved, the error was quite stupid. In the "then" part, res.write(result) did not accept result as argument. This happened when i actually used the corret request (file.data which is a buffer). The other errors occurred everytime i tryed using toString() on file.data, in that case the request wasn't accepted.

Comment: are you using https://github.com/expressjs/multer to parse file uploads? can you confirm if `req.files.file` is a Buffer?

Comment: if it's a buffer, can you try `file.toString('binary')` or `file.toString('utf-8')`? let me know if it works so I can post it as answer

Comment: @Theo i'm not using multer, i'm using express-fileupload. req.files.file contains a json object, req.files.file.data contains a buffer. But for some reason i can't assign that buffer to the computer vision request body field.

Comment: yes that's because documentation says that you should put `image_binary` body, not Buffer
https://github.com/viane/microsoft-computer-vision#analyze-image
can you try file.toString('binary') or file.toString('utf-8')? let me know if it works so I can post it as answer

Comment: It doesn't. In both cases i get an "InvalidImageFormat error. "Input data is not a valid image."

Answer (score 1):

Solved, the request asked for a buffer, and file.data is indeed a buffer. After chacking file.data type in any possible way i started looking for other problems. The error was much easier and, forgive my being stupid, too stupid to be evident. The result was a json, and res.write didn't accept a json as argument.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it with Amazon Recognition Image Classifier, I know its not the same service your using - hoping this helps a little thou:

```
const imagePath = `./bat.jpg`;
const bitmap = fs.readFileSync(imagePath);
const params = {
            Image: { Bytes: bitmap },
            MaxLabels: 10,
            MinConfidence: 50.0
        };
route.post('/', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    let params = getImage();
    rekognition.detectLabels(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('error');
        }else {
            console.log(data);
            res.json(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well... maybe if you explain a bit where does that "upload.single" come from and if your "route" is an express application i could understand better the differences...
Remember i want to avoid having to save the file in local to load it again and then delete it.